# Angular - object $state with property current returning different value than $state.current

Tags: angularjs

I am debugging my angular application and I wish to get the current $state.

When I `console.log($state)`and view the object here is what the parameter 'current' looks like

```
current:
  Object controller:"projectsController"
  controllerAs:"vm"
  name:"app.project"
  templateUrl:"app/controllers/project/template.html"
  url:"/Project/{id}"
```

However, when I `console.log($state.current)`,

Here is how it looks like:

```
abstract:true
name:""
url:"^"
views:null
```

Why are they different? I fail to understand.

My code is simply

```
console.log($state.current)
console.log($state)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait until $state.current resolve. Try this:
`$timeout(function () { console.log($state.current, 'Should console now'); });`

There is better way of handling state change event here:

`$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
   // toState === $state.current
});`